# Rotation in LimeJS

Tags: javascript, limejs

I'm trying to create an animation with rotation. Now I first used a transition loop, but the rotation stops when the animation is done, and then repeats. I'm trying to achieve an animation in rotation which constantly goes on with the same speed. The effect is like using an ENTER_FRAME event in ActionScript 3 and giving the rotation some speed. I tried moving the objects x position succesfully with LimeJS:

```
lime.scheduleManager.schedule(function()
    {
        var pos = this.getPosition(); 
        pos.x += 4;
        this.setPosition(pos);
  }, redsquare)
```

I try to achieve this with rotation aswell, but I don't know if this is possible. I tried this:

```
  lime.scheduleManager.schedule(function()
  {
        var rotation = this.getRotation(); 

        rotation.rotate += 4;

        this.setRotation(rotation);

  }, redsquare)
```

That doesn't work. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using lime.animation.RotateBy.

The documentation is [here](http://limejs.digitalfruit.ee/docs/symbols/lime.animation.RotateBy.html).